# How can I get Xcode to find elements inside a webview for a hybrid app?

Tags: swift, xcode, webview, wkwebview, xcuitest

I’m an SDET on my current position, and I’ve been asked to research whether it’s possible to use Xcode and XCUITest to automate UI testing of a hybrid app. We have one we’re building internally that has a native wrapper around other apps being pulled in as cocoapods. One of these apps is webview-based and that’s the one causing me problems.

I’m comfortable using Xcode and Swift to write UI automation in general, and I’m comfortable using the debugger to analyze an app’s element hierarchy. For this app in particular, however, I am not able to see the elements that are descendants of the webview.

All I get, when I do a po commmand in the debugger, is a block that looks like this:

```
WebView, 0x600002d6c000, {{0.0, 82.0}, {1024.0, 1284.0}}
    WebView, 0x600002d6c0e0, {{0.0, 82.0}, {1024.0, 1284.0}}
        WebView, 0x600002d6c1c0, {{0.0, 82.0}, {1024.0, 1284.0}}
        Other, 0x600002d6c2a0, {{991.0, 87.5}, {30.0, 1267.5}}, label: 'Vertical scroll bar, 2 pages', value: 0%
        Other, 0x600002d6c380, {{11.0, 1333.0}, {1002.0, 30.0}}, label: 'Horizontal scroll bar, 1 page', value: 0%
```

And that’s only useful up to the point of letting me verify that the webview loaded. It doesn’t let me verify anything actually IN it.

Now, I also know from googling that at this point, assuming I’m running my app in a simulator, I can go open Safari and see the source code of the webview. I can confirm this works for me. However, that doesn’t actually tell me whether it’s possible for me to access the webview’s elements from XCUITest automation, and if so, how I need to refer to them. Since I can’t actually see them in my debugger, it’s very difficult for me to actually reach them. Trying to do a UI Recorder session doesn’t work, as the UI Recorder can’t acknowledge the presence of the elements either.

One last thing I also know from googling is that the vast majority of pages I’ve found, including ones right here on Stack Overflow, talk about doing webview-based automation in Appium. However, what I’ve been specifically asked to do is see whether it’s possible in XCUITest in particular.

So my overall question here is: *is* it possible? Is there something I’m missing here in terms of how to get at the webview’s descendants?

I’ve seen discussion of Appium needing to switch “contexts” from a native to a webview context, but I am not finding any references to an equivalent concept in the realm of XCUITest. And I am coming up completely dry in any other useful data.

Editing to add a quick followup remark:

I just did a search on the Apple developer forums, and I see a comment there from someone which may in fact be the root of my problem. They say:

> Same problem here, seems like on ios: 13.3 Webview element is empty :/ while on iOS 13.1 and 13.2 Webview comes with all the elements inside Wbview, any help ?

[Source link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/402040#402040) for this comment for those of you who are in the Apple developer program.

So with this addition in mind, can anyone confirm whether I’ve actually tripped across an Xcode feature change or bug here?

One more edit to add the details on my development environment, as they’re relevant to the question:

- Mac is running latest release of Catalina, 10.15.2
- My Xcode is 11.3.1
- I’m testing against simulators as well as a physical device running iPadOS 13.3, though I’m also about to see if the problem repros against 13.2

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 2):

I’m answering my own question just because this may help someone else, but if anyone else has pertinent data do please say so!

With the guidance of the Apple Developer forums link I referenced in my post, I was able to confirm that I do NOT repro my problem if I build our app against 13.2 instead of 13.3.

So I appear to be tripping across a bug in either Xcode 11.3.1 or in iPadOS 13.3 here. If I build against 13.2, I can see the descendants of my webview just fine.

Any other SDETs/QA Engineers out there, if you’re running into a similar problem and you have the option to do so, you should download a 13.2 simulator and see if you can test against that instead. Or against a device running 13.2 if you have one available.

Comment: This sounds like a RADAR that should be filed.

Comment: @ablarg: Good idea. I need to investigate how to get at Apple’s bug system and see if this has been reported already. I also need to see if it repros against Xcode 11.4’s beta, which is now available.